# How to remove params from url codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, url-rewriting, seo, slug

I have url like this :

> `http://domain/sentencijos/autoriai/429/marselis-prustas`,

where sentencijos is a controller, autoriai is a method, `429(param)` is marselis prustas ID. I want to remove this param (ID) but don't know how.

Full url should look like this:

> `http://domain/sentencijos/autoriai/marselis-prustas`

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: You should be using `routes` for this. `$route['sentencijos/autoriai/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'sentencijos/autoriai/$2';` Just an example.

Comment: @Nil'z: Doing this will make active 2 links for same page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `slug` with `id` in your URLs.

**This is how it works:**

1) I'm assuming here a product website flow.
2) For a particular product page, displaying the product details need some data from the URL (it can be anything `product id`, `product slug`, etc).
3) Using `product ids` in URLs is not considered a good practice. Its neither **`SEO friendly`** nor **`User friendly`**. Below is the example of an URL using `product id`,

> `http://www.example.com/products/123/`

4) Hence, an alternative to this is what is called as **`product slug`**
5) A slug **`(semantic URL or Permalinks)`** is basically a meaningful, seo friendly, human readable sequence of keywords separated by hyphens (or underscores). Below is the example of an URL using `product slug`,

> `http://www.example.com/products/apple-iphone-5S-16GB-brand-new/`

Here, **`apple-iphone-5S-16GB-brand-new`** is a slug.
You can also understand from the URL of this page,

> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800780/how-to-remove-params-from-url-codeigniter`

where,
   **24800780** = this is the unique `question_id`
   **how-to-remove-params-from-url-codeigniter** = this is the `slug` made from your `question`

**How to use slug?**

1) Ofcourse your product page needs some data from URL to understand which product to display.
2) Before we were querying our database using the `id` we are getting from the URL. But now we'll do the same thing (querying our database) just replacing id with slug and thats it!
3) Hence adding an additional column in your database named **`slug`**. Below will be your updated product database structure.

```
id  |  title  |  slug  |  price  |  thumbnail  |  description
```

**In your code:**

Assuming this to be your URL,

```
http://domain/sentencijos/autoriai/marselis-prustas
```

and this `marselis-prustas` might be your `slug value` which your controller function will receive and pass to the model which gradually use this to query the database.
For this, you have to create a new column (as explained above) which should have the value `marselis-prustas` and also other `slugs`.

**Advantages of slug in URLs:**

1) SEO Friendly
2) User Friendly
3) Clean and semantic URLs

Comment: Maybe someone can show code example how to replace id with slug, starting from db? It would be easier. Maybe I can copy my code?

Comment: So, search in database should be from slug. What if I want to search from id but show slug in url.

Comment: So replace the `slug` with `id` in URL and query with `id`