# SEO friendly Blogs links in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a website in CodeIgniter,
In blog section the blog link is

```
http://www.example.com/blogs?id=1
```

But i want links like

```
http://www.example.com/something-something
```

That i have save in database
Please help..

Comment: what you have tried so far? show your code pls

Comment: Tomorrow i can show you the code. But the problem is evry blog link is same. I have set id in GET. But i want link like title of blog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - SEO Friendly URL Structure (Slug Implementation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801084/codeigniter-seo-friendly-url-structure-slug-implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do following steps for making SEO friendly Blogs links in CodeIgniter

Add following code in `/application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['blogs/(:any)'] = 'blogs/$1';
```

Create new controller called `Blogs.php` in `/application/controllers`

```
<?php
class Blogs extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index($param){

        echo $param;

    }
}
?>
```

then, change your URL's in view files.

> http://www.example.com/blogs?id=1

```
http://www.example.com/blogs/1
```

-OR-

```
http://www.example.com/blogs/name-of-the-post
```

Comment: Thanks dude its works. But think about can we create link like this http://www.example.com/name-of-post its more better

Comment: you have blohgpost `id` right, so you can load the blog from database by `id`. then  pass the blog title name inside this function `url_title($title)` it will give like `name-of-the-post`

Answer (score 1):

You can use codeigniter `url_title` method to do so

```
$title = "this is my title?";
$url_title = url_title($title);
// Produces: this-is-my-title
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#url_title