# Url shortener in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to shorten my url

How can I change **this:**

`http://qc-web.local.com/mydata/mydata_view?datemin=2017-03-11&datemax=2017-05-22`

**to this:**

`http://qc-web.local.com/mydata/mydata_view/2017-03-11/2017-05-22`

Comment: Which version of CI do you use?

Comment: zeeshan i'm using codeignitor 3

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: Check if this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801084/codeigniter-seo-friendly-url-structure-slug-implementation/25801646#25801646

Answer (score 0):

You can define `route` in `config/routes.php` as given below:

```php
$route['mydata/mydata_view/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2';

// make sure to replace `controller` with your controller class name
// and `method` with your Controller's method name.
```

Then in the controller's method:

```php
public function method($date_min, $date_max)
{
    var_dump($date_min);
    var_dump($date_max);
}

// `method` should match with method defined in the `routes.php` file.
```

You can read more about [URI Routing here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=uri%20route)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this code in route file

```
$route['mydata/mydata_view/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Mycontroller/index';
```

Add this code in controller

```
public function index($min_date, $max_date)
{
    var_dump($min_date);
    var_dump($max_date);
}
```