# how change query string to segment url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

**hello all**,

this is my first question here hope u'll all understand my problem an help me..

So this is the problem i am working on an application based on **sports community**(***CODEIGNITER***) so when a logged-in user clicks on team name or sports page redirect's to specific team page and the url is like below

http://localhost/project/home?cat_id=MjY=&cat_type=Mg==

where cat_id and cat_type is in `base64encode()`

i want to make it seo friendly.. i already tried this link

[How to Convert Query String to Segment URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317440/how-to-convert-query-string-to-segment-uri)
but nothing happend can any one help me plz

current url is `localhost/project/home?cat_id=MjY=&cat_type=Mg==`

desired url `localhost/project/home/team-category`

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what are you looking for is **slug based URLs ([Semantic URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL))**

---

**So how to implement slug?**

Will explain with an example:
**URL** - http://www.example.com/products/apple-iphone-5S-16GB-brand-new/

1) Assuming you are having a product page and ofcourse product page needs some data from URL to understand which product to display.
2) Before we were querying our database using the `id` we are getting from the URL. But now we'll do the same thing (querying our database) just replacing `id` with `slug` and thats it!
3) Hence adding an additional column in your database named `slug`. Below will be your updated product database structure (just an example).

```
Columns                       Values

id (int(11), PK)              1
title (varchar(1000))         Apple iPhone 5S 16GB
slug (varchar(1000))          apple-iphone-5S-16GB-brand-new
price (varchar(15))           48000
thumbnail (varchar(255))      apple-iphone-5S-16GB-brand-new.jpg
description (text)            blah blah
...
...
```

For this you have to do below changes -

**1) Create below 2 tables**

```
slug_table:

id (PK)   |    slug    |   category_id (FK)


category_table:

id (PK)   |  title  |  thumbnail  |  description
```

**2) config/routes.php**

```
$route['/products/(:any)'] = "category/index/$1";
```

**3) models/category_model.php**

```
class Category_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);
    }

    public function get_slug($slug)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('slug_table', array('slug' => $slug));

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            return $query->row();
        return false;
    }

    public function get_category($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('category_table', array('id' => $id));

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            return $query->row();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**4) controllers/category.php**

```
class Category extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('category_model');
    }

    public function index($slug)
    {
        $sl = $this->category_model->get_slug($slug);

        if($sl)
        {
             $data['category'] = $this->category_model->get_category($sl->category_id);
             $this->load->view('category_detail', $data);
        }
        else
        {
             // 404 Page Not Found
        }
    }
}
```

**5) views/category_detail.php**

```
<label>Category title: <?php echo $category->title; ?></label><br>
</label>Category description: <?php echo $category->description; ?></label>
```

---

I've also answered on slug before. Check if it helps.
[How to remove params from url codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800780/how-to-remove-params-from-url-codeigniter)

Comment: sorry cannot upvote because it need's 15 reputation so just mark ur answer right